# MySQL query two tables with different fields

Tags: mysql

I have two tables with different fields:

```
SELECT url, title, description, impact, solution, severitylevel, category
FROM admin_cyber.sss3wn
WHERE severitylevel = "5" 
AND client = "user1" 
UNION
SELECT name, risk, host, protocol, port, pluginoutput, description, solution
FROM admin_cyber.sss1wn
WHERE risk = "Critical" AND client = "myuser1"
AND datescanned IN (SELECT max(datescanned) FROM admin_cyber.sss1wn
```

Common fields are : client, datescanned

I just want to query two tables and retrieve the data for the latest date only.

Does both tables need to have the exact fields to be in UNION?

Question #2: If I know that the field "url" from sss3wn and "host" in sss1wn are the same meaning, can I group them in one in a common name?

Thanks!
Nathalie

Comment: I think before going any further with Stack Overflow... https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query - and I'm still learning too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the UNION, it doesn't matter if the tables have the same fields or not, since the number of selected columns on both SELECT statements match.

So, both SELECTs will have to select the same number of columns, and matching columns in each SELECT should have the same dataType (you can CAST to force the same dataType if that makes sense).

Example:

```
SELECT 
  url AS Field1, 
  title AS Field2, 
  description AS Field3, 
  impact AS Field4, 
  solution AS Field5, 
  severitylevel AS Field6, 
  category AS Field7,
  "-" AS Field8
FROM admin_cyber.sss3wn
WHERE severitylevel = "5" 
  AND client = "user1" 
UNION
SELECT 
  name AS Field1, 
  risk AS Field2, 
  host AS Field3, 
  protocol AS Field4, 
  CAST(port AS NVarChar) AS Field5, 
  pluginoutput AS Field6, 
  description AS Field7, 
  solution AS Field8
FROM admin_cyber.sss1wn
WHERE risk = "Critical" AND client = "myuser1"
AND datescanned IN (SELECT max(datescanned) FROM admin_cyber.sss1wn);
```

I'm assuming all matching fields have the same dataType (except for solution:NvarChar and port:integer to serve as an example on how you may CAST something). On the 8th field, a constant was selected on the first statement to force the same number of selections between SELECT statements.

It probably doesn't make sense on doing this UNION (it appears to me that the matched fields doesn't have any relation on their meaning) but this is what a UNION would be like.

EDIT:
If in fact, data from both SELECTs are really different (in meaning) and yet you still need to list them as a single result set, you may do something like:

```
SELECT 
  "INCIDENT" AS RowType,
  url AS Url_or_Name, 
  title AS Title_or_Risk, 
  description AS Desc_or_Host, 
  impact AS Impct_or_Prot, 
  solution AS Sol_or_Port, 
  severitylevel AS Lvl_or_Output, 
  category AS Cat_or_Desc,
  "-" AS Field8
FROM admin_cyber.sss3wn
WHERE severitylevel = "5" 
  AND client = "user1" 
UNION
SELECT 
  "CONNECTION" AS RowType,
  name AS Url_or_Name, 
  risk AS Title_or_Risk, 
  host AS Desc_or_Host, 
  protocol AS Impct_or_Prot, 
  CAST(port AS NVarChar) AS Sol_or_Port, 
  pluginoutput AS Lvl_or_Output, 
  description AS Cat_or_Desc, 
  solution AS Field8
FROM admin_cyber.sss1wn
WHERE risk = "Critical" AND client = "myuser1"
AND datescanned IN (SELECT max(datescanned) FROM admin_cyber.sss1wn);
```

Or you may find that it would be best to re-order selected columns to better match their meaning on the union's resulting columns.

Comment: Is there a better way to do instead of UNION?

Comment: Depends... Its not clear what you are trying to achieve there. The 2 selects seems to me like 2 completelly different things. A select statement will render you a "list" of data, organized in columns. You have to think on what this "resulting list" will have to be like... In this case, if you edit your question and post something like "I would excpect the SQL statement to render me a list like this..." and include an example, it would be easier to consider about union being or net the best way to do it.

Comment: And just to be clear: There's nothing technically wrong in rendering a list with column mixing data with different meanings (like what appears to be happening in the SQL Statement that I posted as answer). If that makes sence in your context, it will work. I'm just pointing it out to you, that judging by field names, it appears that you're mixing diff data on same column...

Comment: Thx Marcelo! I have write down my desired columns and match fields from all tables in the right column.  The only issue I had was "The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns" but I have chosen the same number of columns in each Select